# Google account disabled for unknown reason

Tags: google-account

Last night, my Google account was disabled. I don't know how or why. But I'm very worried because this is my personal account, and I have been using it over the past 4 years.

I submitted an appeal by using the contact form in the Gmail Help Center, but they only said that my account is disabled. Do they not know why?

Can anyone guide me on how I could possibly enable it again? And how much time would be required to reactivate my account?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you're not the only one to be hit by this. This topic was discussed extensively [in the Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/nAceyyGtuBE).

It basically boils down to this: Submit an appeal and wait.

I know is very frustrating but there doesn't seem to be much anyone can do, though posting to the forum might catch the eye of a browsing Google employee and speed your cause along.